# Checking Value of Radio Button Group via JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

This may seem silly and downright stupid but I can't seem to figure out how to check the value of a radio button group in my HTML form via JavaScript. I have the following code:

```
<input type="radio" id="genderm" name="gender" value="male" />
<label for="genderm">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="genderf" name="gender" value="female" />
<label for="genderf">Female</label>
```

How do I retrieve the value of `gender` via JavaScript?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

*If you are using a javascript library like jQuery, it's very easy:*

```
alert($('input[name=gender]:checked').val());
```

This code will select the `checked` input with `gender` name, and gets it's `value`. Simple isn't it?

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPu2S/1/)

Comment: The question was "Javascript", not "jQuery".

Comment: @MattiSG, and since it was accepted, I guess it helped the questioner(and many other people)...

Comment: Well, I came across this question looking for a Javascript solution, the question is not tagged jQuery, when I read the question it was not mentioning jQuery, I don't think the accepted answer should have a dependency on jQuery. But that's the power of the crowd, you know  ;)  My own down vote won't change much for all the many other people who you helped with this answer  :)

Comment: check the answers from @darelf for pure js..!!

Comment: JQuery was okay back then.

Comment: i edited the question titlle as i was looking for javascript solution, not jquery so anyone else doesn't get mislead by the former tittle and BTW this avoids to downvote a correct answer regardelss that the original question was aimed to work with javascript

Answer (score 343):

Use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) if you want to avoid frameworks (which I almost always want to do).

```
document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes, `.querySelector()` is the vanilla answer to so many jQuery questions...

Comment: This is a first, I have never before, logged in just to give someone an up vote.

Comment: @Misunderstood same here. Had to log in to vote this up

Comment: This answer makes me sorry that the answer for a question cannot be later changed by the community or moderators. Of course, with all due respect to the chosen answer (towards both individuals involved in that decision).

Comment: I love this answer. No need for cumbersome frameworks if you know what you're doing. :-)

Answer (score 105):

In pure Javascript:

```
var genders = document.getElementsByName("gender");
var selectedGender;

for(var i = 0; i < genders.length; i++) {
   if(genders[i].checked)
       selectedGender = genders[i].value;
 }
```

### update

In pure Javascript without loop, using newer (and potentially not-yet-supported) [`RadioNodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList) :

```
var form_elements = document.getElementById('my_form').elements;
var selectedGender = form_elements['gender'].value;
```

The only catch is that `RadioNodeList` is only returned by the `HTMLFormElement.elements` or `HTMLFieldSetElement.elements` property, so you have to have some identifier for the form or fieldset that the radio inputs are wrapped in to grab it first.

Comment: Plus one for answering the title and not providing a jQuery answer.

Answer (score 9):

To get the value you would do this:

```
document.getElementById("genderf").value;
```

But to check, whether the radio button is **checked** or selected:

```
document.getElementById("genderf").checked;
```

Comment: That wasn't the question. you cannot use `ID` here since you do not know the id, or you might have countless radio buttons, but you want to know which value will be sent to the server (the selected value of the group). So this answer doesn't really answers the question

Comment: @vsync Not sure what you mean, the OP says nothing about servers and asks **(1)** in his title how to check the value and **(2)** how to retrieve the value, both of which I've answered based on the code the OP provided.

Comment: I see I didn't explain it very well: what you proposed will never ever work and doesn't even make sense. you absolutely **cannot** use `getElementById` in this situation. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30917988/104380).

Comment: id arise the problem while getting the value,i have two id in same name it gets only 1st id value not second one

Answer (score 7):

If you wrap your form elements in a form tag with a name attribute you can easily get the value using document.formName.radioGroupName.value.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="radio" id="genderm" name="gender" value="male" />
    <label for="genderm">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="genderf" name="gender" value="female" />
    <label for="genderf">Female</label>
</form>

<script>
    var selected = document.forms.myForm.gender.value;
</script>
```

Comment: This appears to have cross browser issues.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Chrome either. I'm sure it did once. :(

Comment: you forgot `.forms` and `.elements`! so it should be `document.forms.myForm.gender.value`

Comment: Your answer seems so much easier to understand than the others thanks :).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var selectedVal;

for( i = 0; i < document.form_name.gender.length; i++ )
{
  if(document.form_name.gender[i].checked)
    selectedVal = document.form_name.gender[i].value; //male or female
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for ES5+

```
[...document.getElementsByName("gender")].find(input => input.checked).value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without loop:

```
document.getElementsByName('gender').reduce(function(value, checkable) {
    if(checkable.checked == true) 
        value = checkable.value; 
    return value;
}, '');
```

`reduce` is just a function that will feed sequentially array elements to second argument of callback, and previously returned function to value, while for the first run, it will use value of second argument.

The only minus of this approach is that reduce will traverse every element returned by `getElementsByName` even after it have found selected radio button.

Answer (score -3):

```js
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("text").value='male'
 document.getElementById("myCheck_2").checked = false;
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function myFunction_2() {
document.getElementById("text").value='female'
 document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck_2");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
Male: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">
Female: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck_2"  onclick="myFunction_2()">

<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Name">
```