# Javascript functions. variable result. why undefined or doesn't if else statement function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I need the values of the name, address, size, and topping fields to appear in a text box. Without problems the name and address appears correctly. However I can't seen to get the size function to work. It is a radio button, and thus I need only one size to appear. I haven't even tried an if else for the checkbox yet. Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function pizza() {
    document.pizzaboy.comments.value = "Name:" + " " + pizzaboy.name.value + "\n" + "Address:" + " " + pizzaboy.address.value + "\n" + document.getElementById("small").value + document.getElementById("medium").value + document.getElementById("large").value + "\n" + pizzaboy.toppings.value; 
    {
        var rslt = "";
        if (document.pizzaboy.size[0].checked) {
            rslt = rslt + "Size=Small\n";
        } else if (document.pizzaboy.size[1].checked) {
            rslt = rslt + "Size=Medium\n";
        } else rslt = rslt + "Size=Large\n";
        return rslt;
    }
}
</head>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear! I don't see your `<script>` tag over! is it your actual code? and what is that extra `{` after your `function pizza()`?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak The extra pair of curly braces just introduces a new block which isn't associated with any statement. It is useless, but also shouldn't cause errors.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? What are you trying to do with rslt? (From what you posted, you are not doing anything with it.) Are you expecting the size to also show up in the value of comments, and if so, is this intended to include the value of rslt? Some clarification would help.

Answer (score 0):

The second Javascript bracket might be throwing you an error, keeping your code from running correctly.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're referring to. Do you mean the pair of curly braces immediately following the `document....` statement?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Yes that exact pair of curly braces is unnecessary.

Comment: I see. That pair wouldn't actually throw an error, since it just represents an arbitrary block of statements. You're correct that it is unnecessary, though.

Comment: I didn't notice the second closing curly brace, thus why I thought it was throwing an error. My bad, though I can't seem to find anything else wrong without any more code.

Answer (score 0):

In this post, several (more general) ways to get values of radio buttons are explained:

[Checking Value of Radio Button Group via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561625/checking-value-of-radio-button-group-via-javascript)

The first answer is using jQuery, but the following answers will help you i think.
You should try this. Answer here if you need further assistance.