# How can I select the checked value in a form using radio buttons against the answer for a question

Tags: javascript, html

```js
class Question {
    constructor(question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.ansA = ansA;
        this.ansB = ansB;
        this.ansC = ansC;
        this.ansD = ansD;
        this.answer = answer;
    };

    checkAns(ansSelected, answer) {
        if (ansSelected === answer) {
            console.log('Well Done')
        };
    };
};

//Questions
var questionOne = new Question('Where is Creete?', 'Barcalona', 'Greece', 'Dubi', 'Ireland', 'Greece');
var questionTwo = new Question('How many times have Liverppool won the Champions Legue?', '1', '4', '6', '5', '6');
var questionThree = new Question('Where was the first Godfather in the mafia from?', 'Milan', 'Gunoa', 'Rome', 'Napoli', 'Napoli');

//Index of the array with the questions array 
var i = 0;
const arrayQuestion = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree];





//Displaying the first index of the question array on load up
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
document.getElementById('rad1Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
document.getElementById('rad2Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
document.getElementById('rad3Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
document.getElementById('rad4Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;




const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener("click", check);

function check() {
    
    var rad1 = document.getElementById('rad1').checked;
    var rad2 = document.getElementById('rad2').checked;
    var rad3 = document.getElementById('rad3').checked;
    var rad4 = document.getElementById('rad4').checked;
    

    //Checks which button is selected
        if (rad1 == true) {
            alert('Bingo1');
        }
        else if(rad2 == true){
            alert('Bingo2');   
        }       
        else if(rad3 == true){
            alert('Bingo3');   
        }      
        else if(rad4 == true){
            alert('Bingo4');   
        }
};



//Next button which cycles through the array and show the current question.
//With if statement to catch out of bound error
const n = document.getElementById('next');
n.addEventListener("click", next);

function next() {

    i++;

    if (i === arrayQuestion.length) {
        i = 0;
    };

    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
    document.getElementById('rad1Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
    document.getElementById('rad2Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
    document.getElementById('rad3Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
    document.getElementById('rad4Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;
};


//Function to go back to previouse question
//With if statement to catch out of bound error
const p = document.getElementById('previous')
p.addEventListener("click", prev)

function prev() {

    i--;

    if (i === -1) {
        i = arrayQuestion.length - 1;
    };


    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
    document.getElementById('rad1Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
    document.getElementById('rad2Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
    document.getElementById('rad3Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
    document.getElementById('rad4Label').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;

};
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 200;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

button{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="formEl">
            <h2 id="question"></h2>
            
            <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad" value="choice1">
            <label for="rad1" id="rad1Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" value="choice2">
            <label for="rad2" id="rad2Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="rad" value="choice3">
            <label for="rad3" id="rad3Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="rad" value="choice4">
            <label for="rad4" id="rad4Label"></label>

            <button id="previous" type="button" class="userSelection">Previous</button>
            
            <button id="next" type="button" class="userSelection">Next</button>
            
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
    <script src = js/app.js></script>
</html>
```

I am trying to build a quiz using radio buttons and an array to hold questions.

I am having trouble selecting and validating the checked radio button.

I can select a radio button one by one and alert the console but it looks messy. Is there away I can just use the name property and get the checked value?

I will in the future use the checked value to check if it is the correct answer.

```
<HTML>

        <form id="formEl">
            <h2 id="question"></h2>

            <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad" value="choice1">
            <label for="rad1" id="rad1Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" value="choice2">
            <label for="rad2" id="rad2Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="rad" value="choice3">
            <label for="rad3" id="rad3Label"></label>

            <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="rad" value="choice4">
            <label for="rad4" id="rad4Label"></label>

            <button id="previous" type="button" class="userSelection">Previous</button>

            <button id="next" type="button" class="userSelection">Next</button>

            <button id="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>


<JS>
class Question {
    constructor(question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.ansA = ansA;
        this.ansB = ansB;
        this.ansC = ansC;
        this.ansD = ansD;
        this.answer = answer;
    };

    checkAns(ansSelected, answer) {
        if (ansSelected === answer) {
            console.log('Well Done')
        };
    };
};



var questionThree = new Question('Where was the first Godfather in the mafia from?', 'Milan', 'Gunoa', 'Rome', 'Napoli', 'Napoli');



const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener("click", check);
function check() {

    var rad1 = document.getElementById('rad1').checked;
    var rad2 = document.getElementById('rad2').checked;
    var rad3 = document.getElementById('rad3').checked;
    var rad4 = document.getElementById('rad4').checked;


    //Checks which button is selected
        if (rad1 == true) {
            alert('Bingo1');
        }
        else if(rad2 == true){
            alert('Bingo2');   
        };       
        else if(rad3 == true){
            alert('Bingo3');   
        }       
        else if(rad4 == true){
            alert('Bingo4');   
        }
};
```

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30917988/9262488

Comment: @NiK648, Thanks exactly what I was looking for :)